# Oracle Composite Key Auto-Increment (Decrement!?)

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a relatively large table (~100m records) which is basically an XML store. There can be multiple XML documents with different timestamps (with the logic that the latest timestamp = the most recent version). We're expecting monthly batches of updated data, probably with new versions of ~70% of the data.

We're planning on only keeping the most recent 2-3 versions in the store, so I'm guessing our current b-tree index on (record ID, timestamp) is not necessarily the fastest? A straight-forward "select * from table where timestamp >= yyyy-mm-dd order by record id, timestamp" query took 15 hours to complete last night - pretty high-spec kit and I don't think anyone else was using the DB at the time.

(re: the query itself, ideally I only want to select the most recent document with timestamp >= yyyy-mm-dd, but that's less of an issue for now).

Is there any way I can create an auto-*decrement* column, as follows:

```
Record ID   Timestamp    Version   XML
1           2011-10-18   1         <...>
1           2011-10-11   2         <...>
1           2011-10-04   3         <...>
2           2011-10-18   1         <...>
2           2011-10-11   2         <...>
```

etc etc - i.e. as a new version comes along, the most recent timestamp = version 1, and all the older records get version = version + 1. This way my house-keeping scripts can be a simple "delete where version > 3" (or whatever we decide to keep), and I can have a b-tree index on record ID, and a binary index on version?

Hope I'm not barking completely up the wrong tree - have been "creatively Googling" all morning and this is the theory I've come up with...

Comment: Monthly batches work out to about 70 million rows. But daily batches come to about 2.5 million rows a day. If it's even possible to get daily batches, that might be worth thinking about.

Comment: Not a possibility - it's a source-driven decision. It has its benefits, though - it means that these tables pretty much sit idle apart from 1 day a month where the data is inserted into them, and 1 day a month where the latest data is extracted and passed on to the front-end system. So the insert/update has no (practical) time constraints, but the select (and subsequent processing) has a ~72 hour window, of which the select is currently taking 15 hours...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure decrementing the version would be a good idea.. The only way to do it would be with triggers looking up matching record ids and updating them accordingly. This wouldn't be great for performance..

This is how I do something similat in our database environment (which is of a similar size). Hopefully its useful:

Create a seperate archive table that will hold all versions of your records. This will be populated by a trigger on insert to your main table. The trigger will `insert` the current version of the record into your archive, and `update` the record on the master table, incrementing the version number and updating the timestamp and data.

Then, when you only need to select the latest version of all records, you simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

If you need the ability to view 'snapshots' of how the data looked at a given point in time, you will also need `valid_from` and `valid_to` columns on the table to record the times at which each version of the records were latest versions. You can populate these using the triggers when you write to the archive table..

`Valid_to` on the latest version of a record can be set to the maximum date available. When a newer version of a record is inserted, you'd update the `valid_to` of the previous version to be just before the `valid_from` of the new record (its not the same to avoid dupes)..

Then, when you want to see how your data looked at a given time, you query th archive table using SQL like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ARCHIVE_TABLE a
WHERE <time you're interested in> BETWEEN a.valid_from AND a.valid_to
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch work is definitely different than the typical insert/update approach (esp if triggers or many indexes are involved).  Even with decent disks/hardware, you'll find traditional DML approach is very slow with this volume.  For 100mm + tables where you're updating 70mm in batch each month, I would suggest looking into an approach similar to:

1. Load new batch file (70mm) into separate table (NEW_XML), same format as existing table (EXISTING_XML).  Use nologging to avoid undo.
2. Append (nologging) records from EXISTING_XML that don't exist in NEW_XML (30mm recs, based on whatever key(s) you already use).
3. Rename EXISTING_XML to HISTORY_XML and NEW_XML to EXISTING_XML.  Here you'll need some downtime, off hours over a weekend perhaps.  This won't take any time really, but you'll need time for next step (and due to object invalidations).  If you already have a HISTORY_XML from previous month, truncate and drop it first (keep 1 month of old data).
4. Build indexes, stats, constraints, etc on EXISTING_XML (which now contains the new data as well).  Recompile any invalidated objects, use logging, etc.

So in a nutshell, you'll have a table (EXISTING_XML) that not only has the new data, but was built relatively quickly (many times faster than DML/trigger approach).  Also, you may try using parallel for step 2 if needed.

Hope that helps.